# Do guns in Fallout New Vegas use hitscan or fire bullet projectiles?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In New Vegas (and Fallout 3, which runs on the same engine) when using VATS you can see your character fire a projectile which takes time to travel to your opponent, and the health bar only drops when the bullet impacts.

Outside of VATS it's less clear whether bullets work as hitscan or on a ballistics model. When using guns it seems like the weapons are hitscan - enemies take damage the same moment the gun is fired. But other weapons very clearly fire a physical projectile, like a missile, rocket, or ball of plasma which the player can watch as it travels. Conversely, the laser class of weapons fire a hitscan beam which travels instantly to it's target. Even in the slow-motion of VATS a laser beam appears does not seem to travel, it instantly burns an opponent.

I can't tell if a physical bullet only appears in VATS, or exists outside of the assisted targeting system. Outside of VATS, do guns in New Vegas use hitscan or do they fire a bullet projectile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the weapon *and* whether or not you're using VATS.

As you note, plasma and payload weapons are obviously not hitscan.

However, bullet-based and laser weapons are hitscan. From, of all things, [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HitScan#:%7E:text=Fallout%203%20weapons%20appear%20to%20be%20all%20hitscan%20when%20not%20using%20VATS.&text=This%20is%20their%20major%20advantage,targets%2C%20at%20least%20without%20VATS.) :

> This is most obvious when, through mods, using a scope on a normally unscoped weapon. The enemy will drop almost a full half-second before the tracer projectile reaches them at long ranges.

In VATS basically everything is hitscan in a manner of speaking: because the hit-or-miss determination is probabilistic, the behavior of the projectile is determined after the hit-or-miss determination which is also how hitscan works.  This includes payload and plasma weapons, essentially turning a rocket launcher into a hitscan weapon for that one shot.